# Integral $\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}=\sqrt \pi$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals

Hi I am trying to prove this result below
$$
\mathcal{J}:=\int_0^1\frac{dx}{\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}=\sqrt \pi.
$$
The result is quite interesting however I realized I am not familiar with working square roots of log functions like this.  I am more stumped than usual because there isn't much to work with here.  The indefinite integral is given by
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}=-\sqrt \pi\, \text{erf}\left(\sqrt {\log \frac{1}{x}}\right),
$$
although I cannot prove this.  Possibly a proof to this will lead to the result of the definite integral.

It seems the integral is somehow related to a Gaussian integral possibly, I notice the error function and the result $\sqrt \pi$.  A solution would be greatly appreciated and I hope could also be of use to the math community here.

Thanks.  In case anybody likes this integral and is interested in a similar one, here is another one for you:

$$
\int_0^1 \sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}} \,dx=\frac{\sqrt \pi}{2}
$$

Comment: I think these are Gamma function values

Comment: @MPW yes exactly it sure seems like that

Comment: Oops, I did not see the other one, I will edit my post accordingly.

Comment: @PranavArora the other one is just for fun, I am not asking anybody to solve two problems

Comment: Ah ok, but I have got a solution to that, I will post it anyways. :)

Comment: Taking $u=\sqrt{\ln\dfrac{1}{x}}$ would solve the integral.

Comment: @Tunk-Fey Thank you my friend :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Rewrite $\log(1/x)=-\log(x)$ and use the substitution $-\log x=t^2 \Rightarrow dx=-2te^{-t^2}dt$ to obtain:
$$I=\int_0^1 \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}=\int_0^{\infty} 2e^{-t^2}\,dt=\boxed{\sqrt{\pi}}$$

---

For the second one, do the same thing to obtain the integral:
$$\int_0^{\infty} 2t^2e^{-t^2}\,dt$$
Since
$$\int_0^{\infty} e^{-(at)^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a}$$
Differentiate both the sides wrt $a$ to obtain:
$$\int_0^{\infty} 2at^2e^{-(at)^2}\,dt=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2a^2}$$
Substitute $a=1$ to obtain the answer.

Comment: I am going to accept the answer in a minute when the system lets me! :)  +1 Thank you my friend

Comment: Thanks but this integral is far more easier than the other ones you have posted here. :P

Comment: I do not always try to post very difficult integrals, I post integrals that I think people may find interesting.  Difficult or not, they are all beautify :)Thanks I just checked this as the answer, sorry I forgot to yesterday

Answer (score 7):

This is [Euler's first historical integral expression for the $\Gamma$ function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#History). No substitution necessary. The integral is simply $\Big(-\frac12\Big)!=\Gamma\Big(1-\frac12\Big)=\Gamma\Big(\frac12\Big)=\sqrt\pi.~$ QED.

Comment: Yes, that's how I recognized it, thanks for the info. But I think most people today find the form I mentioned most familiar.

Comment: excellent to know, I never knew this!  Thanks a lot @Lucian

Answer (score 4):

Note that
$$\int_0^1\left(\log\frac1x \right)^pdx=\int_0^{\infty}u^pe^{-u}du=\Gamma(p+1)$$
by making the simple substitution $x=e^{-u}$.

Your integrals follow immediately from this.

Comment: Thanks for another solution and insight into the problem.  +1

Answer (score 3):

Integrating by parts, and borrowing @Pranav's value for the first integral,

$$\int_0^1 \sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}} \,dx= x \sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}\big{|}_0^1- \int_0^1 x \frac{dx}{(-2x)\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}\\
=\frac12 \frac{}{}\int_0^1  \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\log \frac{1}{x}}}\\
=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2}$$

Comment: +1 Thanks a lot for your solution David H.  You provide solutions often to my integrals, so thank you for this too.